# How can Class be of the Class class and not have Class instance methods?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, internals, metaclass

I was studying how the Ruby interpreter is implemented, and one question occurred that didn't get an answer yet for me. That's the one in the title: since `Class` (`r_cClass`) has `super` set to itself (ignoring metaclasses, since actually `super` is the metaclass of `r_cClass`), if I send one method to the `Class` object, this will be looked in the method table of `Class`' class. But `Class`' class is `Class`, so shouldn't I end up looking the instance methods of `Class`? But that's not the case since in the documentation `Class` class methods and `Class` instance methods are separated. In the `search_method` in `eval.c` of Ruby, I didn't find any special check for the `Class` class. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: In a question as abstract as this, it's probably a good idea to give specific examples, such as an example of one instance method and an example of one class method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your beliefs about the way it should work seem right, but I'm not sure why you think it doesn't work that way.

In Ruby 1.8.7:

```
irb> a = Class.new.methods - Object.new.methods
=> [... 36 element array ...]
irb> b = Class.methods - Object.new.methods
=> [... 37 element array ...]
irb> b - a
=> ["nesting"]
```

A normal class instance (Class.new) has 36 instance methods. If I look at Class itself, which is also a normal class instance, it has the same 36 instance methods, plus 1 additional class method (nesting), which exists only because it is inherited from its superclass Module.

Note that adding an instance method to Class automatically adds it as a class method as well, but adding a class to Class's metaclass will not.

```
irb> class Class ; def everywhere ; true ; end ; end
irb> class << Class ; def only_singleton ; true ; end ; end
irb> Class.everywhere
=> true
irb> Class.new.everywhere
=> true
irb> Class.only_singleton
=> true
irb> Class.new.only_singleton
NoMethodError: undefined method 'only_in_singleton' for #<Class:0x4800ac8>
```

Comment: So the methods are in fact the same. Actually there is no clue in the source code that led me to this thought. It's just that the Ruby docs clearly separate Class instance method from Class singleton methods. Is that separation made only for clarity?

Comment: By singleton methods you mean class methods?

Comment: Well, I guess my answer is a little wrong, in that I believe ONE method (new) is different. Class.new returns a new anonymous class; Class.new.new returns an instance of that anonymous class. The "public class method" version of new (that returns a new anonymous class) would be defined in Class's metaclass.

Comment: It's tough to write code in comments, so I've updated my answer with an example of adding a method to the metaclass (making it available to Class but not instances of Class).

Comment: That clears it up for me, thank you. `new` is overridden by Class's metaclass, but all the other methods are the same.